# how to stub or mock authlogic current_user in view specs

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, authlogic, rspec-rails

i am trying to write some views specs for my rails app, but i stumble on this error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error:
       undefined local variable or method `current_user' for #<#<Class:0x007fa47d2612d0>:0x007fa47e267710>
```

Here is how i wrote my view spec :

```
describe "/newsletters/index.html.erb" do
  include NewslettersHelper
  include Authlogic::TestCase

  def current_user(stubs = {})
    @current_user ||= mock_model(User, stubs)
  end

  def user_session(stubs = {}, user_stubs = {})
    @current_user_session ||= mock_model(UserSession, {:user => current_user(user_stubs)}.merge(stubs))
  end



def login(session_stubs = {}, user_stubs = {})
    UserSession.stub!(:find).and_return(user_session(session_stubs, user_stubs))
  end



 def logout
    @user_session = nil
  end



context "without a logged-in user" do
    before(:each) do
      activate_authlogic
      logout()
      assigns[:newsletters] = @newsletters = [ mock_model(Newsletter, :titre => "value for titre",
       :sommaire => "value for sommaire", :content => "value for content") ]
    end

it "renders a list of newsletters" do
  # pending("find how to mock authlogic current user in views spec")
  render
  rendered.should have_selector("tr>td") do |row|
    row.should have_content("value for titre")
  end
  rendered.should have_selector("tr>td") do |row|
    row.should have_content("value for sommaire")
  end
  rendered.should have_selector("tr>td") do |row|
    row.should have_content("value for content")
  end
end
```

end

Answer (score 1):

Try `controller.stub(:current_user) { mock_model(User) }`  I think it should help

Comment: i tried your suggestion both in the before(:each) block and directly into the it example block without success, thanks anyway for your answer

Answer (score 1):

The view spec is an isolated context so you need to stub the current_user method in the view context.

```
view.stub(:current_user).and_return(mock_model(User))
```

For further reading on the **view spec** I suggest you the [view spec page](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-14/docs/view-specs/view-spec#passing-view-spec-that-stubs-a-helper-method) on relish

Comment: Both of these worked for me. It's a bit weird, so long as you put anything in the and_return(), even nil, it worked. ```allow(view).to receive(:current_user).and_return(double("User"))
    #allow(view).to receive(:current_user).and_return(@user_w)
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers worked for me (using rspec 3.9 here), as I was getting errors like `#<#<Class:0x007fb9ca387dc8> does not implement: current_user`, trying to stub the view or controller objects, so I had to do it like:

```
  before do
    controller.singleton_class.class_eval do
      # Just defining methods to being stubbed later
      def current_user; end
      def current_account; end
      helper_method :current_user, :current_account
    end
    allow(controller).to receive(:current_user).and_return(user)
    allow(controller).to receive(:current_account).and_return(account)
  end
```

not the prettiest solution, but it worked.